# I am getting following problem while activating tensorflow environment with keras in anaconda

Tags: python, visual-studio, tensorflow, keras

```
  Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1198]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
(base) C:\Users\tanis>conda activate tf_gpu
C:\Users\tanis>python C:\Users\tanis\anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\etc\keras\load_config.py  1>temp.txt
C:\Users\tanis>set /p KERAS_BACKEND= 0<temp.txt
C:\Users\tanis>del temp.txt
C:\Users\tanis>python -c "import keras"  1>nul 2>&1
C:\Users\tanis>if errorlevel 1 (
ver  1>nul
set "KERAS_BACKEND=theano"
python -c "import keras"  1>nul 2>&1
)
C:\Users\tanis>SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
C:\Users\tanis>SET MSSdk=1
C:\Users\tanis>SET "VS_VERSION=15.0"
C:\Users\tanis>SET "VS_MAJOR=15"
C:\Users\tanis>SET "VS_YEAR=2017"
C:\Users\tanis>set "MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL=/AI;/AL;/OUT;/out"
C:\Users\tanis>set "MSYS2_ENV_CONV_EXCL=CL"
C:\Users\tanis>set "PY_VCRUNTIME_REDIST=\bin\vcruntime140.dll"
C:\Users\tanis>set "CXX=cl.exe"
C:\Users\tanis>set "CC=cl.exe"
C:\Users\tanis>set "VSINSTALLDIR="
C:\Users\tanis>for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %i in (`vswhere.exe -nologo -products * -version [15.0,16.0) -property installationPath`) do (set "VSINSTALLDIR=%i\" )
C:\Users\tanis>if not exist "" (for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %i in (`vswhere.exe -nologo -products * -requires Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.v141.x86.x64 -property installationPath`) do (set "VSINSTALLDIR=%i\" ) )
C:\Users\tanis>if not exist "" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\" )
C:\Users\tanis>if not exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\" )
C:\Users\tanis>if not exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\" )
C:\Users\tanis>if not exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\" )
C:\Users\tanis>IF NOT "" == "" (
set "INCLUDE=;"
set "LIB=;"
set "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=;"
)
C:\Users\tanis>call :GetWin10SdkDir
C:\Users\tanis>call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node  1>nul 2>&1
C:\Users\tanis>if errorlevel 1 call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKCU\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node  1>nul 2>&1
C:\Users\tanis>if errorlevel 1 call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKLM\SOFTWARE  1>nul 2>&1
C:\Users\tanis>if errorlevel 1 call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKCU\SOFTWARE  1>nul 2>&1
C:\Users\tanis>if errorlevel 1 exit /B 1
C:\Users\tanis>exit /B 0
C:\Users\tanis>for /F %i in ('dir /ON /B "\include\10.*"') DO (SET WindowsSDKVer=%~i )
The system cannot find the file specified.
C:\Users\tanis>if errorlevel 1 (echo "Didn't find any windows 10 SDK. I'm not sure if things will work, but let's try..." )  else (echo Windows SDK version found as: "" )
Windows SDK version found as: ""
C:\Users\tanis>IF "win-64" == "win-64" (
set "CMAKE_GEN=Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"
set "BITS=64"
)  else (
set "CMAKE_GEN=Visual Studio 15 2017"
set "BITS=32"
)
C:\Users\tanis>pushd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community>CALL "VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat" -vcvars_ver=14.16
The system cannot find the path specified.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community>popd
C:\Users\tanis>IF "" == "" SET "CMAKE_GENERATOR=Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"
C:\Users\tanis>call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node  1>nul 2>&1
C:\Users\tanis>if errorlevel 1 call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKCU\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node  1>nul 2>&1
C:\Users\tanis>if errorlevel 1 call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKLM\SOFTWARE  1>nul 2>&1
C:\Users\tanis>if errorlevel 1 call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKCU\SOFTWARE  1>nul 2>&1
C:\Users\tanis>if errorlevel 1 exit /B 1
C:\Users\tanis>exit /B 0
(tf_gpu) C:\Users\tanis>
```

I have no clue how to fix this. When I go to load_config it already shows backend as TensorFlow. I have visual studio 2019 installed. Is there any way I can change SET "VS_YEAR=2017" to "VS_YEAR=2019" or do I need to install visual studio 2017? I have installed the TensorFlow GPU version and keras. I have also installed Cuda 11.0 drivers with cuDnn v8.0.

Comment: from prompt it looks like tf_gpu is not activated - pls check. Also edit the title to show that the issue is VS-related.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below mentioned steps to install tensorflow and keras in conda virtual environment on Windows OS.

```
(base) C:\Users\xyz>conda create -n tf_gpu
(base) C:\Users\xyz>conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *C:\Users\xyz\Anaconda3
tf_gpu                 C:\Users\xyz\Anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu
(base) C:\Users\xyz>conda activate tf_gpu
(tf_gpu) C:\Users\xyz>pip install tensorflow
(tf_gpu) C:\Users\xyz>python
>>> import tensorflow
>>> form tensorflow import keras
```